# Char concatenation

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation

I have 30 files that I want to open in C.

phantom_atn_1.bin
phantom_atn_2.bin
...
phantom_atn_30.bin

I am trying the following but it doesn't work:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[100],filename1[100],extension1[100];
int fileNum,frameNum;


main()
{
    printf("Test1\n");
    frameNum=30;

    strcpy (extension1, ".bin");

    for (fileNum=1;fileNum<frameNum+1;fileNum++)
    {
        printf("Test2\n");
        strcpy (filename1, "phantom_atn_");
        printf("Test3\n");  
        printf(filename1); 
        printf("\n");  
        printf(filename,"%d", fileNum); 
        printf("Test5\n");  
        sprintf(filename,"%d", fileNum); 
        printf("Test6\n");  
        strcat(filename1,extension1);     
        printf("Test7\n");
        printf(filename);
        printf("Test8\n");
        printf(filename);
        image1=fopen(filename,"rb");
    }
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How `doesn't work`???

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char filename[100];
int fileNum,frameNum;


main()
{
  FILE *fp[30];
  char *extension1 = ".bin";
  frameNum=30;
  for (fileNum=1;fileNum<frameNum+1;fileNum++)
  {
    sprintf(filename, "phantom_atn_%d%s", fileNum, extension1);
    printf("%s\n", filename);
    //I have opened file in write mode here                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    fp[fileNum] = fopen(filename, "w");
    //now you can write anything in file pointer using below code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    fprintf(fp[fileNum], "%d", fileNum);
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked well. Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it!! :)

Answer (score 6):

Why not simply use e.g. [`snprintf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)?

```
snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "phantom_atn_%d.bin", fileNum);
```

([`_snprintf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2ts7cx93.aspx) on Windows)